# Full Database Backup failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, ola-hallengren

I have been using the Ola Hallengren script for a number of years and it works great.

We recently set up a new SQL server and I installed the latest script.

When I run the Full Database backup I get the following error. The directory gets created correctly, but the error doesn't tell me what else it could be. Any help would be appreciated.

#### Error Message

> ```
> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. ...0)  
> Server: FTN-ERP-SQL100 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Version: 15.0.2000.5 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Edition: Standard Edition (64-bit) [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Platform: Windows [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Procedure: [MaintenanceScripts].[dbo].[DatabaseBackup] [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Parameters: @Databases = 'DDX_Bird_Archive', @Directory = 'Z:\Backups', @BackupType = 'FULL', @Verify = 'Y', @CleanupTime = 24, @CleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP', @Compress = NULL, @CopyOnly = 'N', @ChangeBackupType = 'N', @BackupSoftware = NULL, @CheckSum = 'Y', @BlockSize = NULL, @BufferCount = NULL, @MaxTransferSize = NULL, @NumberOfFiles = NULL, @MinBackupSizeForMultipleFiles = NULL, @MaxFileSize = NULL, @CompressionLevel = NULL, @Description = NULL, @Threads = NULL, @Throttle = NULL, @Encrypt = 'N', @EncryptionAlgorithm = NULL, @ServerCertificate = NULL, @ServerAsymmetricKey = NULL, @EncryptionKey = NULL, @ReadWriteFileGroups = 'N', @OverrideBackupPreference = 'N', @NoRecovery = 'N', @URL = NULL, @Credential = NULL, @MirrorDirectory = NULL, @MirrorCleanupTime = NULL, @MirrorCleanupMode = 'AFTER_BACKUP', @MirrorURL = NULL, @AvailabilityGroups = NULL, @Updateability = 'ALL', @AdaptiveCompression = NULL, @ModificationLevel = NULL, @LogSizeSinceLastLogBackup = NULL, @TimeSinceLastLogBackup = NULL, @DataDomainBoostHost = NULL, @DataDomainBoostUser = NULL, @DataDomainBoostDevicePath = NULL, @DataDomainBoostLockboxPath = NULL, @DirectoryStructure = '{ServerName}${InstanceName}{DirectorySeparator}{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}', @AvailabilityGroupDirectoryStructure = '{ClusterName}${AvailabilityGroupName}{DirectorySeparator}{DatabaseName}{DirectorySeparator}{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}', @FileName = '{ServerName}${InstanceName}_{DatabaseName}_{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}_{Year}{Month}{Day}_{Hour}{Minute}{Second}_{FileNumber}.{FileExtension}', @AvailabilityGroupFileName = '{ClusterName}${AvailabilityGroupName}_{DatabaseName}_{BackupType}_{Partial}_{CopyOnly}_{Year}{Month}{Day}_{Hour}{Minute}{Second}_{FileNumber}.{FileExtension}', @FileExtensionFull = NULL, @FileExtensionDiff = NULL, @FileExtensionLog = NULL, @Init = 'N', @Format = 'N', @ObjectLevelRecoveryMap = 'N', @ExcludeLogShippedFromLogBackup = 'Y', @DirectoryCheck = 'Y', @StringDelimiter = ',', @DatabaseOrder = NUL...  
> Version: 2022-12-03 17:23:44 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Source: https://ola.hallengren.com [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)    [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Date and time: 2024-01-22 10:23:08 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Database: [DDX_Bird_Archive] [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> State: ONLINE [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Standby: No [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Updateability: READ_WRITE [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> User access: MULTI_USER [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Recovery model: SIMPLE [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Encrypted: No [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Is accessible: Yes [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Differential base LSN: 73288000000202100092 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Last log backup LSN: N/A [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Allocated extent page count: N/A [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Modified extent page count: N/A [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
>       [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Date and time: 2024-01-22 10:23:08 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Database context: [master] [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Command: DECLARE @ReturnCode int EXECUTE @ReturnCode = dbo.xp_create_subdir N'Z:\Backups\FTN-ERP-SQL100\DDX_Bird_Archive\FULL' IF @ReturnCode <> 0 RAISERROR('Error creating directory.', 16, 1) [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Outcome: Succeeded [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Duration: 00:00:00 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Date and time: 2024-01-22 10:23:08 [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)
>       [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 50000)  
> Date and t...  The step failed.
> ```

Comment: This output is from a  SQL job step and it's truncated. Please take the script from the failing step and execute it in a SSMS window connected to the instance. You will get full output from the procedure  including any errors. That way you should be able to identify and even fix the issue yourself.

Comment: In the job step settings you can increase the amount of space for the logging and results. Worst case take the job step code and run it in SSMS to see what it reports back

Answer (score 1):

#### General Ola Error Debugging

The error message in your question looks like the job step error message. The full details are normally stored in a TXT file with the name similar to this:

```
DatabaseBackup_<JOB_ID>_<STEP_ID>_<YYYMMDD>_<HHMMSS>.TXT
```

This file is located in the default LOG directory of your SQL Server instance (Where the ERRORLOG file is located). This could be:

```
<DRIVE>:\MSSQL15.<INSTANCENAME>\MSSQL\LOG\
```

If you could look up the actual file from the failed backup and add the contents of that file to your question by clicking on [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/335082/edit), then we might be able to help.

Then again, looking at the contents of the file, you might find the actual error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- Based on error it looks like permissions for `SQLSERVERAGENT` were not
  inherited/populated correctly for `Z:\Backups`, run the following to re-populate
  permissions and try again.
- If you have `Z:\Backups` configured as a mount point then the
  pemissions need to be populated for both volume level and the mount point level.

```
$backupPath = 'Z:\Backups\'
$volumePath = Get-Partition |
    where {
        $_.AccessPaths -ne $null -and
        $_.disknumber -ne $null -and
        $_.accesspaths -contains $backupPath
    } |
    Get-Volume |
    select -expandproperty Path;
    
#Arguments to grant full control with inherit permission to the mount
$aceArgs = @('NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT','FullControl','ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit','None', 'Allow')
$accessControlEntry = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $aceArgs;

#Configure permissions to the volume
$acl=[io.directory]::GetAccessControl($volumePath);
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessControlEntry);
[io.directory]::SetAccessControl($volumePath, $acl);

#Configure permissions to the mount point
$acl=[io.directory]::GetAccessControl($backupPath);
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessControlEntry);
[io.directory]::SetAccessControl($backupPath, $acl);
```